# Why the difference in the flow of universal reference and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

Working from the Efficient Modern C++, Item 25. we have an example

#### Case 1

```
class Widget {
public:
template<typename T>
void setName(T&& newName)
{ name = std::forward<T>(newName); }
...
};
```

#### Case 2

```
class Widget {
public:
void setName(const std::string& newName)
{ name = newName; }
void setName(std::string&& newName)
{ name = std::move(newName); }
...
};
```

#### The call

```
Widget w;
w.setName("Adela Novak");
```

Now assuming case 1, the book states that the literal is conveyed to the assignment operator for t std::string inside w's name data member.

Assuming case 2, the book states that -> first a temporary is created from the literal, calling the string constructor, so the setName parameter can bind to it, and than this temporary is moved into w's name data member.

#### Question

Why does this difference in behavior come about and how am I to think about it?

Namely, why is there no need for a temporary in case 1? Why is there  difference? Is T&& not deduced to be an rvalue reference to a string, thus arriving at the same behavior as case 2 (obviously not, as per the book, but why)?

Comment: Show the declaration of `name` (and its class's assignment operator declaration if not a standard class)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Of course... It seems trivial now when you have told me. Please provide an answer bellow, so I can accept and close the question.

Comment: I believe the term 'universal reference' has been superseded by the term 'forwarding reference'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case 1, `T` is deduced to be `const char (&)[12]`, not `std::string`. There is no reason for the compiler to promote the string literal to `std::string` yet. In case 2, every overload requires takes a reference to an `std::string`, which forces the creation of a temporary `std::string` to which a reference can be bound using the implicit `const char*` constructor.

Note that while an rvalue reference such as `std::string &&` may only bind to an rvalue, the templated equivalent `T &&` may bind to both rvalues and lvalues.